# Double meaning of "Short" for object dimensions

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Let's suppose you go to Ikea to buy a wardrobe, but you have to make sure it fits in your room.

You find two that are really nice and since you like them so much you decide to buy both of them.

So you measure their *length*, *width* and *height* (just to be sure they fit in your room).

For the *width* you have no problem: They could be *thicker* or *narrower* and would still fit.

However the first wardrobe *length* is not good. It's too *long* so you write in comments: Please provide a *shorter* one.

The second wardrobe *length* is good but its *height* is not. This one is too *tall* so you write in comments: Please provide a *shorter* one.

Wardrobe A is *too large* so it must be ***shorter***.

Wardrobe B is *too tall* so it must be ***shorter***.

Because *shorter* has two meanings you end up receiving both wardrobes with  incorrect sizes.

Now the question:

Is there a pair of words for *length* and *height* that avoid using the same word to mean *less magnitude*?

Comment: Whether ***shorter*** means *less length* or *less height* is normally contextually obvious (it nearly always applies to whichever dimension is larger, in the referent). But there's nothing absolute about any of the three spatial dimensions anyway, so the heels on your footwear could just as well be *thinner/thicker* instead of *longer/shorter* (the latter being perhaps more likely when talking about stiletto heels).

Comment: Usually you can’t buy closets at Ikea, closets come with the house,  wardrobes are typically, tall, wide, and deep and can be taller or shorter, wider or narrower, and deeper or shallower.

Comment: Thanks. Deeper and shallower makes sense. And I changed closet for wardrobe.

Comment: @Jim i think you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: Specify that you want greater/lesser length or greater/lesser height.  Don't expect a generic term like "shorter" to be unambiguous without further qualification.  (And as Jim suggests, "depth" is the usual dimension for a closet-like item, not "length".)

Answer (score 1):

You have confused some terms.  When facing an object (esp. from the front), it has width (x), height (y), and depth (z).  You called the depth 'width'.  Length refers to the longest dimension of an object, although some dimensions may be excluded in the context (furniture may use the context of a 2D floor plan, and moving objects may use the 1D context of the direction of motion).

'Short' (or any other descriptor of linear dimension) can suffer from lack of a defined context.  You should specify 'shorter height' or 'shorter width' to get a wardrobe that fits.